# How to get access token of telegram's telegraph account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegraph

I would like to create and edit pages on Telegram's telegraph.ph website through telegraph API.

https://telegra.ph/api#createPage

To do so, I need to know the `access token` of the telegraph account. I've been searching high and low using Google how to do it but still can't find any answer.

I am using telegraph python library.

https://github.com/python273/telegraph

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API endpoint you're looking for is [createAccount](https://telegra.ph/api#createAccount). Invoking this endpoint returns an object containing an accesstoken.

From the docs:

> On success, returns an Account object with the regular fields and an additional `access_token` field.

Having said that, the library you've mentioned makes it much easier to work with the api. You don't even to know the `access_token` explicitly. You only need to call `.create_account()` and the library will manage the token internally ([see here](https://github.com/python273/telegraph/blob/df18a3db6165dfad915e5b89768ad7d269c11961/telegraph/api.py#L82) and [here](https://github.com/python273/telegraph/blob/df18a3db6165dfad915e5b89768ad7d269c11961/telegraph/api.py#L26) to know how).

Here is a sample code on how to use the lib to create an account and utilize it:

```
from telegraph import Telegraph

telegraph = Telegraph()

acc = telegraph.create_account(short_name='1337')

print(acc)

response = telegraph.create_page(
    'Hey',
    html_content='<p>Hello, world!</p>',

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Upvoted.
Clearer now but there are still things that puzzles me. What if I already have an existing account? How do I get the access token of an existing account? It doesn't sound reasonable to create a new account everytime I want to do something with the API.

Comment: you can simply pass the access_token to the `Telegraph` constructor in that case and you wont need to call `create_account`

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to get the access_token of an existing telegraph account in the first place. Search google everywhere but still can't find an answer.

Comment: mhm.. call `telegraph.get_access_token()` maybe?

Comment: Thanks. It's a step forward. However, it seems like I have to `create_account` first before I can use `get_access_token()`.

Comment: oh I doubt you can recover an account if you've already lost the `access_token` though. The best you could do is to create a new one and keep the token safe. I wish you find a better solution. cheers.

Comment: seems like you're right. i wonder why it's designed this way. If I hold the account, it should be ok for me to retrieve my own access token.

Answer (score 5):

There is no available endpoints to obtain actual `access_token` on Telegraph API.
But... If you really need to obtain exactly yours Telegraph access_token,
You can get it by accessing devtools in browser, while authenticated in Telegra.ph via their bot.

It passed as a cookie `tph_token` and being sent to check authorization at `https://edit.telegra.ph/check` endpoint.

Look at `Network` tab in your devtools, switch to `XHR` requests filter, then choose `check` request ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPhwc.png))

At the bottom of devtools window, you will see another appeared window, with `Headers` tab selected.

Go to `Cookies` and then you will see your token, that you can use as an `access_token`

It's not an endpoint, by I'm sure, that you can use that instruction to automate obtaining that token, by capturing and parsing some requests, or passing auth url from Telegraph bot expicitly to your python project.
*I don't know how. Somehow. But sure, that if you want, my answer will help you to create obtaining algorithm*

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question.

To add on to [Tibebes. M's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62357019/3848207), there seems to be no way to get the access token of an existing Telegraph account. So, the only way is to create the account first, then note down the returned access token. Reuse this access token in future. Otherwise, one will have to create a new account whenever a new Telegraph message is posted. I don't know why Telegraph is designed this way because it will result in many stale accounts but that's just the way it is.